# Css calc : How should I use the following formula correctly

Tags: css, mobile, font-size, calc

Take into account the different representation of the font sizes of `ios` and `Android` devices by using calc vw and px

I have found the code below on a website.

It works fine, so that the differences between the font-size of ios and android devices (smartphones) is quite good.

But now I want to minimize the font-size because on the ios devices (especially on a iPhone X) it is to big.

```
@media only screen and (max-width:812px) and (orientation:landscape){
main #content .adresse{
font-size: calc(0.88889vw + 11.33333px);  
}
}
```

I experimented a bit and found out that calc(4vw + -15px) is better (quite good) than the origin example.

My question now is:

What is the formula behind this calculation? How can I determine the size of the font so that the difference between ios and android is not to big and the font size is smaller?

Comment: both the formulas don't take into account the OS of the user: just the viewport width and orientation.

Comment: Yes I know, but if you choose only one size (px or rem etc.) the difference between an ios- and an android-device becomes very big. For example, if I use 0.8 rem, it looks pretty good on an iPhone X, but on an Android (version 9) the font becomes much too small. That's why I searched the net and found this example... But it doesn't fit completely or I don't know what the formula is to adapt it even better.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you use this formula: https://websemantics.uk/tools/responsive-font-calculator/  . More than that use rem and set a fix value on HTML, then the rem will calculate based on that and the function above also uses parameters like difference between min/max font-size and min/max viewport size. I find it very useful

Comment: thanks a lot! I will try it and write about my experience.